# NHibernate Unit Of Work Example

Tags: nhibernate

I am looking for a very Simple HTTP module I can look at as a starting point for my MVC/NHibnerate Project.  I am just looking for something that has some simple transaction support and handles opening a session factory and closes it on a per request biases. Has anyone seen a good example of this? I have googled around quite a bit and havent found anything that is both simple and supports transactions.

Thanks

Comment: This is asked several times before. Can you explain what is not simple or what you cannot figure out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked at this [post](http://weblogs.asp.net/srkirkland/archive/2009/09/03/asp-net-mvc-transaction-attribute-using-nhibernate.aspx) and this [post](http://hackingon.net/post/NHibernate-Session-Per-Request-with-ASPNET-MVC.aspx) and adapted them to my use as I think this is the best approach. I found that the session per request module works ok but I found that sessions were opening and closing for static files that did not exist etc. Even though opening and closing sessions are not expensive it did not sit well with me.

Using the attribute on the controller or method means that I am in a bit more control!